# Visual C++ - MIDI Player

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, midi

I am creating an application that needs to play midi files.
I tried this code:

```
SoundPlayer^ player = gcnew SoundPlayer();
player->SoundLocation = path2+"\\aw.mid";
player->Load();
player->PlaySync();
```

It tells me that it can play only wave files. Can I make it play midi files somehow? Or can I use another code?
E: Now I have the NAudio library, but I can't find the code that would play my midi.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is nothing in .net framework alone that allows you to play midi files. Try using the [NAudio library](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) instead, it's open source. From their home page:

> NAudio is an open source .NET audio and MIDI library, containing
>   dozens of useful audio related classes intended to speed development
>   of audio related utilities in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

NAudio may be a good solution, but I've found that in my experience, the code is kinda spaghetti and doesn't explain itself well. Here's a sample of some code for a midi player from the OpenMidiProject, you'll need to download their source files (headers, libs, and dll's) but I've been loving working with their stuff. Basically, what this library does is that it will parse and play the midi events automatically by itself.

If you have any questions about working with this code, don't hesitate to ask. It *does* compile, so if you have any problems getting this to compile it has to be on your end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "..\\MIDIIO\\MIDIIO.h"
#include "..\\MIDIData\\MIDIData.h"
#include "..\\MIDIClock\\MIDIClock.h"
/* Don't forget to add MIDIIO(d).lib to your project */
/* Don't forget to add MIDIData(d).lib to your project */
/* Don't forget to add MIDIClock(d).lib to your project */

int main () {
  long lTimeMode = 0;
  long lTimeResolution = 0;
  long lTempo = 60000000 / 120; /* [microsec/quarter note] */
  long lEndTime = 0;
  long lOldTime = 0;
  long lCurTime = 0;
  MIDIOut* pMIDIOut = NULL;
  MIDIData* pMIDIData = NULL;
  MIDITrack* pMIDITrack = NULL;
  MIDIEvent* pMIDIEvent = NULL;
  MIDIClock* pMIDIClock = NULL;

  pMIDIOut = MIDIOut_Open ("Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth");
  if (pMIDIOut == NULL) {
    printf ("MIDIOut Open failed.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  pMIDIData = MIDIData_LoadFromSMF ("test.mid");
  if (pMIDIData == NULL) {
    printf ("MIDIData Load failed.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  lTimeMode = MIDIData_GetTimeMode (pMIDIData);
  lTimeResolution = MIDIData_GetTimeResolution (pMIDIData);
  lEndTime = MIDIData_GetEndTime (pMIDIData);

  pMIDIClock = MIDIClock_Create (lTimeMode, lTimeResolution, lTempo);
  if (pMIDIClock == NULL) {
    printf ("MIDIClock_Create failed.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  printf ("Now playing...\n");
  MIDIClock_Start (pMIDIClock);

  while (lCurTime <= lEndTime) {
    lCurTime = MIDIClock_GetTickCount (pMIDIClock);
    forEachTrack (pMIDIData, pMIDITrack) {
      forEachEvent (pMIDITrack, pMIDIEvent) {
        long lTime = MIDIEvent_GetTime (pMIDIEvent);
        if (lOldTime <= lTime && lTime < lCurTime) {
          if (MIDIEvent_IsTempo (pMIDIEvent)) {
            long lTempo = MIDIEvent_GetTempo (pMIDIEvent);
            MIDIClock_SetTempo (pMIDIClock, lTempo);
          }
          if (MIDIEvent_IsMIDIEvent (pMIDIEvent) ||
            MIDIEvent_IsSysExEvent (pMIDIEvent)) {
            unsigned char byMessage[256];
            long lLen = MIDIEvent_GetLen (pMIDIEvent);
            MIDIEvent_GetData (pMIDIEvent, byMessage, 256);
            MIDIOut_PutMIDIMessage (pMIDIOut, byMessage, lLen);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    lOldTime = lCurTime;
    Sleep (5);
  }
  MIDIClock_Stop (pMIDIClock);
  printf ("Now end.\n");

  MIDIClock_Delete (pMIDIClock);
  MIDIData_Delete (pMIDIData);
  MIDIOut_Close (pMIDIOut);
  return 1;
}
```